# Is it possible to detect links within an NSString that have spaces in them with NSDataDetector?

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsdatadetector

First off, I have no control over the text I am getting. Just wanted to put that out there so you know that I can't change the links.

The text I am trying to find links in using `NSDataDetector` contains the following:

```
<h1>My main item</h1>
<img src="http://www.blah.com/My First Image Here.jpg">
<h2>Some extra data</h2>
```

The detection code I am using is this, but it will not find this link:

```
NSDataDetector *linkDetector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:nil];
NSArray *matches = [linkDetector matchesInString:myHTML options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [myHTML length])];

for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) 
{
   if ([match resultType] == NSTextCheckingTypeLink)
   {
      NSURL *url = [match URL];
      // does some stuff
   }
}
```

Is this a bug with Apple's link detection here, where it can't detect links with spaces, or am I doing something wrong?

Does anyone have a more reliable way to detect links regardless of whether they have spaces or special characters or whatever in them?

Comment: What about regular expression; e.g. `regularExpressionWithPattern:@"src=(\"|')(.*)(\"|')>"` and then `[match rangeAtIndex:2]`

Answer (score 4):

I just got this response from Apple for a bug I filed on this:

> We believe this issue has been addressed in the latest iOS 9 beta. 
>   This is a pre-release iOS 9 update.
>
> Please refer to the release notes for complete installation
>   instructions.
>
> Please test with this release.  If you still have issues, please
>   provide any relevant logs or information that could help us
>   investigate.
>
> iOS 9 https://developer.apple.com/ios/download/

I will test and let you all know if this is fixed with iOS 9.

Answer (score 1):

You could split the strings into pieces using the spaces so that you have an array of strings with no spaces. Then you could feed each of those strings into your data detector.

```
// assume str = <img src="http://www.blah.com/My First Image Here.jpg">
NSArray *components = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
for (NSString *strWithNoSpace in components) {
    // feed strings into data detector
}
```

Another alternative is to look specifically for that HTML tag. This is a less generic solution, though.

```
// assume that those 3 HTML strings are in a string array called strArray
for (NSString *htmlLine in strArray) {
    if ([[htmlLine substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 8)] isEqualToString:@"<img src"]) {
        // Get the url from the img src tag
        NSString *urlString = [htmlLine substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(10, htmlLine.length - 12)];
    }
}
```

Comment: This need to be dynamic, not just hardcoded to this one URL. There could be multiple URLs of different lengths in this one string, and all could have spaces in them.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a very hacky way to solve my issue. If someone comes up with a better solution that can be applied to all URLs, please do so.

Because I only care about URLs ending in `.jpg` that have this problem, I was able to come up with a narrow way to track this down.

Essentially, I break out the string into components based off of them beginning with `"http://` into an array. Then I loop through that array doing another break out looking for `.jpg">`. The count of the inner array will only be `> 1` when the `.jpg">` string is found. I then keep both the string I find, and the string I fix with `%20` replacements, and use them to do a final string replacement on the original string.

It's not perfect and probably inefficient, but it gets the job done for what I need.

```
- (NSString *)replaceSpacesInJpegURLs:(NSString *)htmlString
{
    NSString *newString = htmlString;

    NSArray *array = [htmlString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\"http://"];
    for (NSString *str in array)
    {
        NSArray *array2 = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@".jpg\""];

        if ([array2 count] > 1)
        {
            NSString *stringToFix = [array2 objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *fixedString = [stringToFix stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];

            newString = [newString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:stringToFix withString:fixedString];
        }
    }

    return newString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSRegularExpression` to fix all URLs by using a simple regex to detect the links and then just encode the spaces (if you need more complex encoding you can look into `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` and there are plenty of examples out there). The only thing that might take you some time if you haven't worked with `NSRegularExpression` before is how to iterate the results and do the replacing, the following code should do the trick:

```
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"src=\".*\"" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
if (!error)
{
    NSInteger offset = 0;
    NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:myHTML options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [myHTML length])];
    for (NSTextCheckingResult *result in matches)
    {
        NSRange resultRange = [result range];
        resultRange.location += offset;

        NSString *match = [regex replacementStringForResult:result inString:myHTML offset:offset template:@"$0"];
        NSString *replacement = [match stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];

        myHTML = [myHTML  stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:resultRange withString:replacement];
        offset += ([replacement length] - resultRange.length);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this regex pattern:**  `@"<img[^>]+src=(\"|')([^\"']+)(\"|')[^>]*>"`  with ignore case ... Match index=2 for source url.

regex demo in javascript: (Try for any help)

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dN6rS1/1)**

Answer (score 0):

Give this snippet a try (I got the regexp from your first commentator  user3584460) :

```
NSError *error = NULL;
NSString *myHTML = @"<http><h1>My main item</h1><img src=\"http://www.blah.com/My First Image Here.jpg\"><h2>Some extra data</h2><img src=\"http://www.bloh.com/My Second Image Here.jpg\"><h3>Some extra data</h3><img src=\"http://www.bluh.com/My Third-Image Here.jpg\"></http>";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"src=[\"'](.+?)[\"'].*?>" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];

NSArray *arrayOfAllMatches = [regex matchesInString:myHTML options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [myHTML length])];

NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:myHTML options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, myHTML.length)];



for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in arrayOfAllMatches) {
    NSRange  range = [match rangeAtIndex:1];

    NSString* substringForMatch = [myHTML substringWithRange:range];
    NSLog(@"Extracted URL : %@",substringForMatch);

}
```

In my log, I have :

```
Extracted URL  : http://www.blah.com/My First Image Here.jpg
Extracted URL  : http://www.bloh.com/My Second Image Here.jpg
Extracted URL  : http://www.bluh.com/My Third-Image Here.jpg
```

Answer (score -1):

You should not use NSDataDetector with HTML. It is intended for parsing normal text (entered by an user), not computer-generated data (in fact, it has many heuristics to actually make sure it does not detect computer-generated things which are probably not relevant to the user).

If your string is HTML, then you should use an HTML parsing library. There are a number of open-source kits to help you do that. Then just grab the href attributes of your anchors, or run NSDataDetector on the text nodes to find things not marked up without polluting the string with tags.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but can you show me in some documentation where it says `NSDataDetector` should not be used on HTML? Just so I know this is actually true.

Comment: This answer is really good…   but I think you aren't aware what kind of impression you made with your last comment.

Comment: Since you work at Apple, I kindly request that you please get the docs updated to reflect the details in your answer. I had NO idea that NSDataDetector was "intended for parsing normal text" (whatever "normal" is) and "has many heuristics to actually make sure it does not detect computer-generated things", which Apple hasn't described what that really means either... what is a "computer-generated thing" anyway? Please push this onto your documentation guys. I've wasted hours on this when proper docs would have saved me.

Comment: @Zero I know what he's meaning by "normal text", but when someone is talking about very technical logical software development, you can't leave it up for interpretation with vague statements. I need Apple to tell me specifically what is and isn't allowed when using detectors. That's my problem with the answer. A small company I may let slide, but Apple is the most valuable company in the world... there are no excuses here.

Comment: I have filed a bug to improve the documentation.

Comment: Mmmh...I've just tested the same portion of code with this string : @" HELLO http://www.blah.com/My First Image Here.jpg WORLD!". Result : "http://www.blah.com/My". I may not understand what "normal text" is?

Comment: This is not a valid URL. In a valid URL spaces are encoded as %20.

Answer (score -1):

URLs really shouldn't contain spaces. I'd remove all spaces from the string before doing anything URL-related with it, something like the following

```
// Custom function which cleans up strings ready to be used for URLs
func cleanStringForURL(string: NSString) -> NSString {
    var temp = string
    var clean = string.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
    return clean
}
```

Comment: No can do... the string is a huge HTML page. I can't remove all of the spaces in the entire page. I need this fixed for just the URLs. And also, many websites have URLs with spaces in them, regardless of whether they shouldn't or not. In my case, I can't control the source of the HTML.